# How to split the fields using regex - java

Tags: java, regex

I am having following log

```
   06-09-2013 14:22:33 127.0.0.1 - 127.0.0.1 80 GET 304 207 410 HTTP/1.1 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0 cs_vi=- cs_uuid=- cs_si=- http://clickstream.local/
```

How to split the log into fields. I had tried like `log.split(" ")` Since user agent contains space in between so its working differently.

I was searching about issue so i came to know regex can be used.

Any `regex` to split the log by fields.

**Output** can be

```
06-09-2013, 14:22:33, 127.0.0.1, etc
```

Any idea will be greatful.

Comment: show us your expected output

Comment: i know you're looking for regex but have you considered using the StringTokenizer(); object? edit: for example 
`StringTokenizer() strToken = new StringTokenizer(str, " "); `

and then use a while loop to go through the tokens?

Comment: What was wrong with `str.split(" ");`?

Comment: @Qben In the log you can see `Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0` it is one string . if i am using  str.split(" ") then it will split user agent also.

Comment: Is this Apache log or some other log?

Comment: Is the data always like this, in other words what if there is a different user agent or different fields ?

Comment: By "etc" do you mean `06-09-2013, 14:22:33, 127.0.0.1, -, 127.0.0.1, 80, GET, 304, 207, 410, HTTP/1.1, 127.0.0.1, Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0, cs_vi=-, cs_uuid=-, cs_si=-, http://clickstream.local/`?

Comment: We need the full output. In other words, what does `etc` replace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this log is produces using `Apache` I would suggest to change the `LogFormat` to make the string more suited for parsing. Changing this might not be an option though.

My two suggestions below expect the log string to looks the same when it comes to number of log parameters.

First option would be to use this example that does not include that much `regexp` but is a bit cleaner. Might be very slow though.

```
public class RunMe {

    public static final int AGENT_INFO_START=12;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int i=0;
        StringBuffer logElement = new StringBuffer();
        ArrayList<String> logElements = new ArrayList<String>();
        String string = new String("06-09-2013 14:22:33 127.0.0.1 - 127.0.0.1 80 GET 304 207 410 HTTP/1.1 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0 cs_vi=- cs_uuid=- cs_si=- http://clickstream.local/");         

        String[] elements = string.split("\\s");
        for(String element : elements) {
            logElement.append(element);
            i++;
            if(i > AGENT_INFO_START && i < elements.length-4) {
                logElement.append(" ");
            } else {
                logElements.add(logElement.toString());
                logElement.setLength(0);
            }

        }

        for(String element : logElements) {
            System.out.println("Field: " + element);
        }
    }
}
```

I guess to `regexp` this would make the code somewhat hard to understand, and since I am in no means a good regexp generator there is most likely a better `regexp` than this one.

```
public class RunMe {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        StringBuffer logElement = new StringBuffer();
        ArrayList<String> logElements = new ArrayList<String>();
        String string = new String("06-09-2013 14:22:33 127.0.0.1 - 127.0.0.1 80 GET 304 207 410 HTTP/1.1 127.0.0.1 Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:21.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/21.0 cs_vi=- cs_uuid=- cs_si=- http://clickstream.local/");

        // Put "" around all fields.
        String newStr = string.replaceAll("^([0-9-]*)\\s([0-9:]*)\\s([0-9\\\\.]*)\\s(-)\\s([0-9\\\\.]*)\\s([0-9]*)\\s(GET|POST)\\s([0-9]*)\\s([0-9]*)\\s([0-9]*)\\s([a-zA-Z0-9\\\\./]*)\\s([0-9\\\\.]*)\\s(.*)\\s(cs_vi=.*)\\s(cs_uuid=.*)\\s(.*)\\s(.*)", 
                                            "\"$1\" \"$2\" \"$3\" \"$4\" \"$5\" \"$6\" \"$7\" \"$8\" \"$9\" \"$10\" \"$11\" \"$12\" \"$13\" \"$14\" \"$15\" \"$16\" \"$17\"");

        String[] elements = newStr.split("\"");
        for(String element : elements) {
            System.out.println(element);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
/(\d\d-\d\d-\d\d\d)\s(\d\d:\d\d:\d\d)\s(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})\s(\d+)\s((:?GET)|(:?POST))\s(\d{3})\s(\d{3})\s(\d{3})\s([^ ]+)\s(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})\s(.+)\s(cs_vi[^ ]+)\s(cs_si[^ ]+)\s(.+)$/
```

This should extract the fields. But I'm not 100% sure, if it's right, since I don't know the exact format of your logfile and I'm just working based on the sample you provided.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the concept of backreferences!

It is pretty straighforward. Just write a regex for the log file and for every field that you want to capture, put that pattern part of the regex in paranthesis:(). This creates a back reference and you can create a fresh string out of the regex using back references.

for your log:

read the log entry into a String variable and then use string.split("regex");

Eg:

If your log is

```
 06-09-2013 14:22:33 127.0.0.1 - 127.0.0.1 80 GET
```

your code will look like this:

```
String string = " 06-09-2013 14:22:33 127.0.0.1 - 127.0.0.1 80 GET";
String regex = "(/d+\-/d+\-\d+)\s?(\d+\:\d+\:\d+)\s?(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})\s?\s?(\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3})\s?(\d+)\s?(\w+)";
string.split(regex);
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Sorry, but you regex is really unreadable, and there is no backreference at all!

Comment: The regex is complex, I agree.
let me give you a new regex 
**(\d+-\d+-\d+)\s(\d+:\d+:\d+)\s(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)\s-\s(\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)\s(GET|POST)\s(\d+)**

Comment: @sp00m It's a regex buddy!!! It's is meant for parsing all possible scenarios. I don't quite understand, what part of the regex you can't read. Is it the \s? (That means space (optional). 
Also, I said **you may use the concept of backreferences**, I don't think I implied, that I'll be using them!!!